# Disk image growing in size

Tags: dd, raw-disk

I am trying to set up Rasberry pi for jobs that don't deserve bigger machine.

I downloaded a Pidora disk image (`.img`) zipped it is roughly 512MB.

After unzipping it is 2.2GB ( no problem here).

After I try to write it to an SD card  with `sudo dd of=~/disk.img if=/dev/sdb`

bash claims that it copied 4.1 GB ( roughly the size of SD card), and SD card happens to be empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your command has "if" and "of" reversed. That would copy your blank sd card into your img file.